# How does one use rescue in Ruby without the begin and end block

Tags: ruby, exception, error-handling, rescue

I know of the standard technique of having a `begin <some code> rescue <rescue code> end`

How does one just use the `rescue` block on its own?

How does it work, and how does it know which code is being monitored?

Comment: http://www.rubyinside.com/21-ruby-tricks-902.html

Answer (score 258, accepted):

A method "def" can serve as a "begin" statement:

```
def foo
  ...
rescue
  ...
end
```

Comment: Also, class definitions, module definitions and (I think) `do`/`end` block literals form implicit exception blocks.

Comment: can you do def rescue ensure end as well?

Comment: You can absolutely do def rescue ensure end as well :-)

Comment: can you use more than one rescue in your def?

Comment: @marriedjane875 yes you can use multiple rescues, either explicitly (each rescue clause/block on its own line) like `rescue TypeError; rescue NameError` -- or you can comma-separate the exception classes, e.g. `rescue TypeError, NameError`

Answer (score 53):

You can also rescue inline:

```
1 + "str" rescue "EXCEPTION!"
```

will print out "EXCEPTION!" since 'String can't be coerced into Fixnum'

Comment: How do you rescue and show the exception backtrace inline ?

Comment: how to return the actual exception?

Comment: Inline rescue is not a good practice as it rescues `StandardError` and all its subclasses, like `NameError` – meaning that even a typo in your code won't raise an error.. See https://thoughtbot.com/blog/don-t-inline-rescue-in-ruby.

Answer (score 30):

I'm using the def / rescue combination a lot with ActiveRecord validations:

```
def create
   @person = Person.new(params[:person])
   @person.save!
   redirect_to @person
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
   render :action => :new
end
```

I think this is very lean code!

Answer (score 22):

Example:

```
begin
  # something which might raise an exception
rescue SomeExceptionClass => some_variable
  # code that deals with some exception
ensure
  # ensure that this code always runs
end
```

Here, `def` as a `begin` statement:

```
def
  # something which might raise an exception
rescue SomeExceptionClass => some_variable
  # code that deals with some exception
ensure
  # ensure that this code always runs
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Bonus!  You can also do this with other sorts of blocks.  E.g.:

```
[1, 2, 3].each do |i|
  if i == 2
    raise
  else
    puts i
  end
rescue
  puts 'got an exception'
end
```

Outputs this in `irb`:

```
1
got an exception
3
 => [1, 2, 3]
```