# what does "rescue false" mean inside if condition in ruby

Tags: ruby, error-handling, rescue

I am ruby newbie and have one question.

```
if (new_account.save rescue false)
   # when account save success
else
   # when account save has error
end
```

I am not sure what rescue false means in this code.
Thanks

Comment: It means you have a crappy code base...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1542703/525478

Comment: Not a perfect dupe, but close....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A one-line rescue is syntactic sugar

```
foo.bar rescue false
# same as
begin
  foo.bar
rescue
  false
end
```

So your code is pretty much the same as this

```
result = nil
begin
  result = new_account.save
rescue
  result = false
end

if result
  # when account save success
else
  # when account save has error
end
```

The `rescue false` means that an exception thrown inside `new_account.save` is treated the same as it returning `false`. In my opinion, this is **bad design**. `new_account` is clearly designed to have two different failure cases, but the calling code ignores it. This code is extremely likely to hide actual bugs occurring inside the saving method.